# Timeline animation in JavaFX

Tags: animation, javafx, timeline

I've been trying to add an animation to my bubble chart in my UI but have ran into some issues. I'm trying to increase the size of the bubble at different stages to show a gradual change but its just drawing it at its full size instead of at every stage.

Here's the timeline code

```
   tl.getKeyFrames().add(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(30), 
    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        //for (XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series : liveDemoBubbleChart.getData()) {
        for(int i = 10; i>0; i--) {
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5,5, ProjectProperties.getInstance().getSportsTweetsCount()/i));
        }
```

The sport tweet count is the final value for the bubble and I'm dividing it by different amounts to show the build up to the final value.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this isn't working as I expect?

Answer (score 2):

The `KeyFrame` taking a `Duration` and an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` simply executes the `EventHandler`'s `handle(...)` method after the time specified by the `Duration`. So your code causes the entire `for` loop to be executed after a pause of 30 seconds.

You probably want to supply a `KeyValue` instead, providing a property to be set and the target value after 30 seconds. The value will then be interpolated at times in between. Have a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm#BEIIDFJC) to see if it helps.